# When trying to send data through https getting 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error'

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am trying to send https req using an API. I have used this sniped of code and getting error while trying to getOutputStream from the connection. In this function, first i have created a connection then trying to connect using either http/https. then just parse the response into an array using connection.getOutputStream. This code working fine for http only.

```
  public String sendNativePost(String httpURL, Map headers, String body, String respType)
  throws Exception {

URL url = new URL(httpURL);
HttpURLConnection connection;

if (url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https")) {
  url = new URL(null, httpURL, new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
  trustAllHosts();
  HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  https.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
  connection = https;
} else {
  connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
}

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

if (headers != null) {
  for (Object key : headers.keySet()) {
    connection.setRequestProperty((String) key, (String) headers.get(key));
  }
} else {
  logger.error("Header is Empty");
}

connection.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
connection.setReadTimeout(10 * 1000);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty(
    "User-Agent", SMSServer.APPLICATION_NAME + "_" + SMSServer.APPLICATION_VERSION);
try (OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
  byte[] input = body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  logger.debug("get body-");
  os.write(input, 0, input.length);
  logger.debug("write body");
} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("Output Stream Error!", e);
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String responseMessage = "";

while (true) {
  String line = br.readLine();
  if (line != null) {
    responseMessage += line;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

br.close();
connection.disconnect();

return responseMessage;
```

}

And got the following error:

```
2022-06-13 17:17:41:323 ERROR HttpClient:224 - Output Stream Error!
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at smsclient.HTTPClient.sendNativePost(HTTPClient.java:217)
    at smsclient.SMSClientHttp.sendPOST(SMSClientHttp.java:256)
    at smsclient.SMSClientHttp.sendSMS(SMSClientHttp.java:147)
    at smsclient.SMSClientHttp.processSMS(SMSClientHttp.java:42)
    at smsclient.HTTPClientMessageSender.run(HTTPClientMessageSender.java:75)
```

Please let me know if you need anymore info

Comment: (1) that code must be ancient; it hasn't been necessary to specify sun.net.www handlers for 20 years (2) it's extremely unlikely you can figure out internal_error from the client end; this needs to be investigated and maybe debugged on the server

Comment: I dont have access to the server, from server its giving Alert error code 80.. can you give me some update on how i can upgrade the code.

Comment: You can and should remove the specification of the handler class, but I don't expect that to solve the problem. Assuming not, that alert gives you _no_ information about the cause or solution; there's a good chance it can't be solved on the client _at all_ and if it can you might have to try thousands or even millions of things before hitting the right one, which could take many years.

Comment: i have solved the issue. :) SSLFactory is the key. By using sslfactory and bind it with the https connection has done the trick. also needed to remove  https.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);             
 this part of code. thanks anyway

Comment: You probably know that code using setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY) should not go to production, since it permits MITM attacks. It might be required in dev if you are using self signed certs.